# Is there a cv command to update extensions?

Tags: cv

Silly question I guess but I can't find in `list` an option to perform extension update with `cv`.

Is that possible?

EDIT 1: is there a possibility for a `ext:update` option that would perform individual update such as `cv ext:update my-extension` or a bulk update `cv ext:update all`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An "update all" option doesn't exist.  For myself, I have a PHP script (below) that returns a JSON file with the extensions that need upgrading.

This is part of a larger [Ansible role](https://github.com/MegaphoneJon/ansible-role-upgrade-civi) which takes that JSON and runs `cv ext:upgrade` on each extension and commits them to version control individually (which is why I return the version number and human-friendly name as well).

Instead of using my Ansible, if you have `jq` and `xargs` installed, you can run this instead to upgrade every extension:

```
upgradeable-civi.php | jq '.[] | .key' | xargs cv ext:download --force
```

This is slightly more complicated, but will upgrade all extensions in one shot, which is faster (clear cache/reconcile managed entities only once, instead of between each extension)

```
upgradeable-civi.php | jq '.[] | .key' | tr '\n' ' ' | xargs cv ext:download --force
```

My script:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
eval(`cv php:boot`);

$e = new CRM_Admin_Page_Extensions();
$localExtensionList = $e->formatLocalExtensionRows();
$remoteExtensionList = $e->formatRemoteExtensionRows($localExtensionList);
$upgradeableExtensions = [];
$i = 0;
foreach ($remoteExtensionList as $e) {
  if ($e['upgradelink'] ?? FALSE) {
    $upgradeableExtensions[$i]['key'] = $e['file'];
    $upgradeableExtensions[$i]['name'] = $e['name'];
    $upgradeableExtensions[$i]['version'] = $e['version'];
    $i++;
  }
}
print_r(json_encode($upgradeableExtensions));
```

Comment: One note - if you have extensions that need upgrading but are currently uninstalled, this will install them on upgrade!  To avoid that, add the `--no-install` flag to the end of my command, then run `cv ext:upgrade-db` at the end - which only upgrades installed extensions.

Comment: that's an answer! thanks a lot

Comment: would you update extensions first or upgrade core first? We're writing a shell script to automate for Drupal and you're code will become a part of.

Comment: @GuillaumeSorel I recommend reviewing my linked Ansible playbook.  Even if you're not familiar with Ansible it's quite readable, look at the "name" field on each stanza to see what step I'm doing there.

Comment: sure we'll have a serious look!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to update the extension folder and run

```
cv ext:upgrade-db
```

Comment: Pradeep, this command upgrades the DB but doesn't operate the update of the extensions themselves. We usually perform it after manual update if needed. My concern is the do the update with cv.